# Error Code 0x80073712 installing KB4041681 & KB4041083

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Error is happening on Windows 7 SP1 x86 running in a VM on Orcale Virtual Box.

Getting an error Code 0x80073712 installing KB4041681 & KB4041083 through Windows Update. I have tried manually installing these updates, I have tried just about everything I can find and cannot resolve my issue.  I'm also getting the same error code when I try to install Visual 2017 Build tools or .NET 4.7.

**Results of running System File Checker**

```
c:\Windows\System32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
```

It looks like others have got help with similar errors by posting the error and their CBS.log.  Uploaded the truncated version of my CBS.log here. https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai9R9F0A3bajhycmT_DyVhzZA9Ww

There are four files that seem to get repeated in the log as being corrupted

> cryptsvc.dll
>   cryptnet.dll
>   d3dcompiler_47.dll
>   wintrust.dll

Here are the first detailed entries in the CBS.log reporting the file corruption.

```
2017-10-11 13:04:49, Error                 CSI    00000430@2017/10/11:17:04:49.559 (F) d:\w7rtm\base\wcp\primitiveinstallers\fileinstaller.cpp(1482): Store corruption detected in function CFileInstaller::ChangeFileCompression expression: 0
  MissingFileSystemResource on resource [109]"\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-cryptsvc-dll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23769_none_785f66471253418f\cryptsvc.dll"[gle=0x80004005]
2017-10-11 13:05:01, Error                 CSI    00000431@2017/10/11:17:05:01.406 (F) d:\w7rtm\base\wcp\primitiveinstallers\fileinstaller.cpp(1482): Store corruption detected in function CFileInstaller::ChangeFileCompression expression: 0
  MissingFileSystemResource on resource [109]"\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-cryptnet-dll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23769_none_19790dfc7359acea\cryptnet.dll"[gle=0x80004005]
2017-10-11 13:05:13, Error                 CSI    00000432@2017/10/11:17:05:13.533 (F) d:\w7rtm\base\wcp\primitiveinstallers\fileinstaller.cpp(1482): Store corruption detected in function CFileInstaller::ChangeFileCompression expression: 0
  MissingFileSystemResource on resource [122]"\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-directx-d3dcompiler_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23796_none_eb8e769493af6438\d3dcompiler_47.dll"[gle=0x80004005]
2017-10-11 13:05:22, Error                 CSI    00000433@2017/10/11:17:05:22.867 (F) d:\w7rtm\base\wcp\primitiveinstallers\fileinstaller.cpp(1482): Store corruption detected in function CFileInstaller::ChangeFileCompression expression: 0
  MissingFileSystemResource on resource [109]"\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-wintrust-dll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23769_none_f20e06a81194d8a9\wintrust.dll"[gle=0x80004005]
```

Comment: "I'm also getting a similar error" - Similar error or same error.  Update your question and provide the required clarification.

Comment: It is the same error code, in a different context. Not even sure that is relevant but thought I'd mention it. I updated the question.

Comment: I assume you have already ran SFC and verified you don't have any corrupted system files?    Have you also reset Windows Update?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes,I ran SFC and it pointed me to the CBS.log I've uploaded and linked. I have NOT reset Windows Update. I have updated the question with those details. I have tried so many things, I could write a book. So I don't want to write everything I've tried in the question so someone would actually read it. Thank you for asking detailed follow up questions.

Comment: File isn't accessible so give us the highlights of which files are corrupt.  Update your question once you have reset Windows Update.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry I didn't realize that link died already. I threw the CBS.log up to a public link on OneDrive and updated my question with the link.  Do you have any thoughts on the log before I reset Windows Update?

Comment: Can't you simply provide which files that log indicates were corrupt.  Will make it easier to help you.

Comment: @Ramhound no problem, I have updated the question with more details about the corrupted files being reported. Sorry, I am a software developer wadding in the deep end of Windows Update here. Not sure what details are important.

Comment: So what is the last cumulative update that was successfully installed?

Comment: cannot figure out how to check what latest cumulative update I have installed. i don't see anything in Windows Update history or add/remove programs.

Comment: the files are part of the [may rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019264/windows-7-update-kb4019264). download the MSU, [expand the MSU and CAB](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-unzip-a-cab-file). now replace the bad files with the good copies.

Comment: i found 3 of the 4 files in the msu from the May Rollup. i wasn't able to find d3dcompiler_47.dll. any idea where to get a good copy of that one? i'm going to start writing up my solution as part of my Q for what I did so far. if you want to post your own answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: okay, i think i found where to get the d3dcompiler_47.dll from. i'm updating my solution section in the original question with my final solution. again, fee please post an answer so I can give you credit. thank you all that helped.

Comment: no, you wrote a good answer. I posted it as community wiki answer

Answer (score 1):

[@magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981) identified in the [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1258265/error-code-0x80073712-installing-kb4041681-kb4041083#comment1850562_1258265) that `cryptsvc.dll`, `cryptnet.dll` & 
 `wintrust.dll` came from the [May Rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019264/windows-7-update-kb4019264)

I did some Googling of `x86_microsoft-windows-directx-d3dcompiler_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23796_none_eb8e769493af6438\d3dcompiler_47.dll` and this pointed me back to [KB 4019990](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019990/update-for-the-d3dcompiler-47-dll-component-on-windows) where I was able to extract a good copy of `d3dcompiler_47.dll` from.

2. Extract files from update

I first used

```
expand windows6.1-kb4019264-x86_aaf785b1697982cfdbe4a39c1aabd727d510c6a7.msu -f* c:\temp\kb4019264
```

Then

```
cd c:\temp\kb4019264
expand Windows6.1-KB4019264-x86.cab -F:* .\kb4019264\Windows6.1-KB4019264-x86
```

3. Replace

I found each of the dlls in the Windows6.1-KB4019264-x86 and then copied it to the correct location in C:\Windows\WinSxS. For each file

a. Set Owner of folder and file to myself

```
e.g. C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-cryptsvc-dll_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23769_none_785f66471253418f
```

For me the folder was already there, there was just no file present at all. I'm guessing others might see the folder completely missing or the folder and file present, but file being otherwise corrupt.  Added myself as a user on the folder and gave myself full control of the folder by going to folder properties and using Advance button on Security tab

b. Copied the good copy of the dll to the folder.

c. For consistency and security, I changed the owner of the folder and the new file just created back to NT SYSTEM\TrustedInstaller user and removed myself as a user on the folder and file

I was now able to successfully install all pending Windows Updates including KB4041681 & KB4041083 above, and install .NET Framework 4.7 and VS 2017 Build Tools.